# linking pages from navigation bar

Tags: divshot

How do I link to pages I have created in divshot from the navigation bar, while still staying in the divshot app.

When I preview, I want to be able to click on links in the navigation bar and go to different pages I have created.

Comment: This is hard to answer as it stands; could you include more information, possibly some example code that you've tried and problems you've run into. It may help to read the [FAQ page](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to understand how best to ask a question

Comment: This a question specific to www.divshot.com web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We haven't built in the ability to link between pages in Divshot just yet, unfortunately. It's been one of our most frequently requested features and is something that we're working on putting in soon.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to make a function that zaps you to the page you want. When you finish the mockup you will be able to replace the code with the real function that changes the page.

```
<script>
var pages = [
  {name: 'page1', url: 'https://api.divshot.com/previews/whateverthelinktothepreviewpage1is'},
  {name: 'page2', url: 'https://api.divshot.com/previews/whateverthelinktothepreviewpage2is'}
  ]

function gotoPageByName( pageName ) {
  for ( var i in pages ) {
    if ( pages[i].name == pageName) {
      window.location = pages[i].url
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

then

```
<a href="javascript: gotoPageByName('page1');" class="btn">Change Page</a>
```

Comment: @Michael : if the url is not permenent, maybe you want to have permanent urls to the last version of the page (then it redirects to the exact page if the cookie is set or whatever security feature is implemented)